# List references by (last name, first) in Elsevier article

Tags: bibliographies, elsarticle

I have tried the responses from various other posts surrounding bibliographies, but they don't seem to resolve my issue - I can't seem to get the reference section to list authors by Last name, First initial. Instead, I get the first name then last name, although it looks like they are still being sorted by last name (i.e. S.A. Mednick is listed before D. Memmert, etc.).

This is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[authoryear,a4paper,12pt,twocolumn,preprint]{elsarticle}
\title{XYZ}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{placeins}
%%\usepackage{natbib} % not needed, as automatically loaded by the document class
\journal{NeuroImage}
\begin{document}    
...    

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{biblio}   
\end{document}
```

I'm using TexStudio. What do I need to add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bibliography style that's in use -- it's set as the argument of `\bibliographystyle` -- determines how all bibliographic entries are formatted.

To obtain your desired formatting, you should (a) switch from the `plainnat` bib style to the `elsarticle-harv` bib style and then (b) rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more in order to fully propagate all changes.